# Error de compilacion con ArrayList

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo java y al realizar este ejercicio me da error de compilación el código y me aparece subrayado la palabra ArrayList con el siguiente mensaje:

" The type ArrayList is not generic, is cant not be parameterized with arguments "

y en la consola me aparece:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Empleado>
    The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Empleado>

    at programacionGenerica.ArrayList.main(ArrayList.java:7)
```

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    package programacionGenerica;

public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<Empleado>();
        
// listaEmpleados.ensureCapacity(11); <-------------- Con esto podrias darla capacidad al ArrayList para que no indefinido.

        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Ana", 45, 2500));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Antonio", 55, 2000));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Maria", 25, 2600));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Mar", 45, 1600));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Toni", 25, 3600));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Pere", 45, 1500));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Joaquin", 35, 4500));
        listaEmpleados.add(new Empleado("Yopni", 65, 7400));
        
        for (Empleado e : listaEmpleados) {
            System.out.println(e.dameDatos());
        }
    }

}

class Empleado {
    
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private double salario;
    
    public Empleado (String nombre, int edad, double salario) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.salario = salario;
    }
    
    public String dameDatos() {
        return "El empleado se llama " + nombre + ". Tiene una edad de " + edad + " años y un sueldo mensual de "
                + salario + "€.";
    }

}
```

Gracias y perdonad si es algo muy basico pero estoy comenzando.

Comment: Te está tomando como `ArrayList` tu propia clase, a la que también llamaste ArrayList, y la cual obviamente no es genérica. Te recomiendo que cambies el nombre de tu clase para evitar conflictos. Nunca uses nombres idénticos al de otras clases, solo sirve para tener problemas. Cámbialo por ejemplo a `EjercicioArrayList` y listo.

Comment: Mil Gracias !!! Sabia yo que la estaba liando por algún lado !!!